# Lightning components/builder/salesforce1?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I wish a very happy new year to all the community members here! This forum has really been very helpful and has saved me a lot of time(and job too:)) many times.

I am reading a lot about `Lightning components/salesforce1` online, looks like Lightning is still evolving & i am overwhelmed with the variants of this component.

I see these terms `Lightning process builder, Lightning components, Lightning apps, Lightning app builder,` etc., can anybody direct me to a link which clearly shows the components used for salesforce1 versus webapp(classic) and where the Lightning Components fit in into these?

Comment: this discussion might help you to understand some of these.. http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/103457/lightning-app-builder-vs-developer-console-new-lightning-app-vs-community-buil

Answer (score 3):

Process builder = workflow.  Server-side automation, no UI.  Processes will run regardless of UI (classic, new desktop, s1, API, communities).

Components--can be made into apps, or used inside other components.  Some from SFDC, some from AppExchange, or build your own with code.  Also available in communities templates.

Apps--components organized together.  Can communicate via lightning events.

App builder--a drag/drop UI for arranging and configuring components into an app. The apps produced from it can be used in S1.

Apps (coded, not via app builder) can be used in classic--they get their own tab.

Components can also be used in LIghtning Experience (new desktop UI) as part of a pilot on record detail pages.

Under the covers, everything in S1 and LEX is lightning components.