# Community Builder Templates with Site.com Pages

Tags: site.com, community, community-builder

I'm currently using a Community Builder Template for my Community Napili Template , given that there are UI customization limitations when using Community Builder Template, is it possible to use Site.com builder to develop new pages then append or expose that page within the Community Builder Template? or does community builder pages and Site.com pages work separately and cannot be combined when creating community pages?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Site.com will be  completely separate from the community builder going forward infact from Spring 16 release .Community builder is the future

The community builder now has more flexibility to build pages .Lets take a look at possible options now using Napili to sort of completely replace UI

> 1)You can create your own lightning template page .It can be either from the object or you can choose from assigned Templates

[image]

> 2)There are options to override the Navigation and header if you want to build your own

[image]

> 3)Since the standard template is all lightning based you can use community builder and replace any standard components with your own

[image]

> 4)There is an option to sparingly use your own CSS overrides for existing standard components

[image]

> 5)Apart from the layout options provided I have mentioned in step 1 ,if you still want to customize further ,you can build your own layouts.You will need to implement an interface known as forceCommunity:layout and add your styles .

Here is a quick sample code to help you with

```
<aura:component implements="forceCommunity:layout" access="global">
<aura:attribute name="column1" type="Aura.Component[]" required="false">   </aura:attribute>
<aura:attribute name="column2" type="Aura.Component[]" required="false">    </aura:attribute>
 <div class="container">
    <div class='contentPanel'>
      <div class='left'>
       {!v.column1}
       </div>
    <div class='right'>
      {!v.column2}
     </div>
   </div>
   </div>
 </aura:component>
```

With all those toolset provide you should be able to completely customize to what you need and sky is limit with community templates going forward .All you need is skills to build lightning components

Comment: Sigh. thought it would be possible to combine both pages. Oh well, good to know that there will be improvements in the future for the Community Builder. Thanks heaps @Mohith

Comment: @SeanSoriano Check the updated response .This is great question mate .

Comment: Cheers mate. Thanks for a quick and detailed answer.

Comment: gud answer @MohithShrivastava.. jus be careful that not all standard components can be used in community builder.. seems there's a difference in app builder vs community builder containers.. pls chk this discussion.. http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/103457/lightning-app-builder-vs-developer-console-new-lightning-app-vs-community-buil

Comment: I implemented couple communities. As long as you implement proper interface all good