# Community Builder vs Force.com Sites

Tags: force.com-sites, community, community-builder

To create a site in Salesforce there are two options available "Community Builder" and "Force.com" Sites. Are there any article or documentation available, which provides comparison between these two options ("Community Builder" and "Force.com Sites")?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I agree with your answer ,community cloud has gone long way now with Napili Templates.

Because everything can be now customized using community lightning builder ,you can create your customized experience completely .You can build your own lightning pages and drag lightning components .

There is ability to customize CSS as well .With lightning components allowed in community builder and since template layouts can be changed anytime ,community templates are the future.

With visualforce you lose point and click ability and will require a developer to maintain the site for long term .

Check out my earlier answer to explore how we can customize [community templates](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/108771/community-builder-templates-with-site-com-pages/108772)

Comment: Mohith, Thanks for providing more details on "Community Builder". I checked your earlier answer as well. I found it very useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For one of the website, we need to choose between "Community Builder" and "Force.com" sites.

While going through different articles, I found a good article which compares "Community Builder and Force.com Sites" :

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_communities_implementation.meta/salesforce_communities_implementation/communities_sites_which.htm

Based on this, I understand that if we would like to use more "Out-of-Box" & Declarative features to create website, we should go with "Community Builder".

If we need more dynamic website including complex APEX code and customization of VF page, we should go with "Force.com" site.

Answer (score 1):

Go with communities.

Sites was the first external content hosting capability (circa 2009?) on what is now the Customer360 Platform.
Its capabilities were limited to securely exposing data in custom objects to Code on the site, visualforce code.

Since then, Communities, with the WYSIWIG builder and templates, content targeting, the salesforce CMS (to manage content for use on salesforce, or other sites), CMS connect (to intake content from other CMS systems), Lightning (JS based UI), and LWC (based on modern web components, which run faster inthe browser than Angular or older technologies) have been introduced, and the UI experiences possible are far greater, achievable far faster than sites would enable.

here is another post with a comparison:
https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9062I000000g7qhQAA